# More clearly discourage questions that only link to code

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users, behavior

I don't know if it's just me, but I believe I'm seeing a rise in StackOverflow questions that contain no code in the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), and related tags and just a link to JSBin or JSFiddle.

The problem is made worse when new users ask their first question in those tags and get a comment saying "*could you put your code in a fiddle?*" I imagine next time they go to ask a question, they just create the fiddle and link to it, thinking that they're being a good SO community member and  following advice that the commenter gave them the first time around.

I know this has been discussed before and been deemed a problem, but I haven't really seen a meta answer that proposes a solution. **I'd like this question to be focused on figuring out ways to discourage "link only" questions that would be valid if the code was in the question itself.**

A few thoughts to get things going:

- The only thing in the FAQ that I can find that remotely relates to this is the "[What questions can I ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)" section:

  > We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code

  I propose adding a more explicit guideline about *just* linking to external sites, something like:

  > Feel free to link to a sandbox site so that potential answerers can easily interact and modify your code, but don't forget to include your source code in your question as well!
- It seems like it should be easy enough to warn the asker that they have no code in the question. I know that there *are* probably some questions that are valid without including source code, but a warning before posting wouldn't hurt:

  > We noticed you didn't include any source code. Remember that just providing a link to the code in question isn't enough. Please provide the code you're having trouble with inside the question text.

Related:

- [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code)
- [Encourage Questions to Include Code Samples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140097/153691)