# Community FAQ: Make subsection headers linkable

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems like it would be useful if we could link directly to a subsection of the Community FAQ.

When I encounter a poor question, I try to point new users to information about asking good questions, recently I added the following comment to a question:

> You're likely to get more help if you include more info in your
>   question. Some links about asking questions: [How do I ask questions
>   here?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), [How to Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [Community FAQ: Asking
>   questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

I included the last one ([Community FAQ: Asking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)), because the first section is about asking questions. But, if I had wanted to link to information from a different section, I would have needed to say something like "follow this link and then search for the section entitled XXX." Not nearly as useful as linking directly to the pertinent section.

The third link is "[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)", I'm suggesting that each header on that page be an anchor link. Some examples:

This link would lead to the section "Asking questions"
`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites#Asking_questions`

This link would lead to the section "Editing and Formatting"
`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites#Editing_Formatting`

This link would lead to the section "Moderation"
`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites#Moderation`

I did a search for questions containing "Community FAQ" and searched the most likely results for "link", the only mention I found was [Experimental Stack Exchange /faq Improvement Project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95160/experimental-stack-exchange-faq-improvement-project). It had an item:

- it is not easy enough to link to specific sections in the /faq

But that was referring to the faq page for each site.

Comment: The third link is for a question that is tagged [meta-tag:faq]. It would not be possible to do what you are asking, if not enabling it for every question, which is not what I think desirable.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno You didn't say why it wouldn't be possible, is it because the `name` attribute can't be used with `<a>` tags?

Comment: As you discovered, only two attributes can be set.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: What do you mean? All the links on the Community FAQ point to separate questions, just link to the question directly.

Comment: The question is about pointing to a subsection that contains numerous links to questions. For instance the "Editing and Formatting" section contains links for 13 questions. Rather than inserting the 13 links to those questions, it would be simpler to insert one link to the header for that section.

Comment: Would also be useful if the ToC on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work actually worked.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) and only the `href=""` and `title=""` attributes are allowed on the `<a>` tag. Others are stripped out on the server, so my suggestion isn't possible.

The `id` attribute isn't allowed either.